# Can I use the same ResultSet statement object in if-else ladder with different query?

Tags: java, oracle, jsp

```
<%
String s1=request.getParameter("cmpname");

String s2=request.getParameter("bname");

String s3=request.getParameter("oname");

Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","manager");

Statement stmt=con.createStatement();

ResultSet rs=null;
**if( !(   s1.equals("") && s2.equals("") && s3.equals("")   ))**//only this is executing
{

  rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from comp where operating='"+s3+"' and name='"+s1+"' and prolong='"+s2+"'");

}
*else if( (s1.equals("") && s2.equals("")) || (s1.equals("") && s3.equals("")) || (s2.equals("") && s3.equals("")) )* 
{
if( (s1.equals("") && s2.equals("")) )
      rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from comp where operating='"+s3+"'");
else if( (s1.equals("") && s3.equals("")) )
      rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from comp where prolong='"+s2+"'");
else if( (s2.equals("") && s3.equals("")) )
      rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from comp where name='"+s1+"'");
 }
 *else
 {* 
    if( s1.equals(""))
          rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from comp where operating='"+s3+"' and      prolong='"+s2+"'");
    else if( s2.equals(""))
          rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from comp where operating='"+s3+"' and name='"+s1+"'");
    else if( s3.equals(""))
          rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from comp where name='"+s1+"' and prolong='"+s2+"'");
  }
 while(rs.next())
 {

  String componentName=rs.getString("name");
  String author=rs.getString("author");
  String domain=rs.getString("domain");
  String programmingL=rs.getString("prolong");
  String opersys=rs.getString("operating");
  String fun=rs.getString("functionality");

    test=false;
 }
%>
```

Only the first result set statement is executing.
I am getting blank page when the second and third condition becomes true.
Please suggest me the correct code for correct execution. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please show us what you're trying to do?  It's not at all clear from the question.

Comment: <%
String s1=request.getParameter("cmpname");
String s2=request.getParameter("bname");
String s3=request.getParameter("oname");
//connection to oracle statements
//ResulSet rs;
if( !(   s1.equals("") && s2.equals("") && s3.equals("")   ))
{
   rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from comp where operating='"+s3+"' and name='"+s1+"' and prolong='"+s2+"'");
}
else if( (s1.equals("") && s2.equals("")) || (s1.equals("") && s3.equals("")) || (s2.equals("") && s3.equals("")) ) 
{
 if( (s1.equals("") && s2.equals("")) )
    rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from comp where operating='"+s3+"'");
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code above, you're not actually trying to use the same `ResultSet` object repeatedly, which is what you asked about.  All you're trying to do is to use the same `ResultSet` variable.  It's not the same thing.

Anyway, your problem is actually nothing to do with `ResultSet`s.  I don't think the conditions in each `if` are what you intended.  In particular

```
if( !(   s1.equals("") && s2.equals("") && s3.equals("")   ))
```

will be true, unless all three variables are empty strings.  In that case, you'll go into your first `else if`, but you'll never get to the final `else`.  I suspect you didn't even test the case where all three variables are empty strings.

I strongly suspect that in that first `if`, you intended to write

```
if( !(   s1.equals("") || s2.equals("") || s3.equals("")   ))
```

which is the same as saying that all three variables have non-empty values.